# Display text on hover over Custom Console Component

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer-console, servicecloud, service-cloud-console

I have a Custom Console Component(displayed in console) which when clicked on opens a vf page. I want to display text "Test" whenever user points its mouse over this component. How can i do this? This component is visible to all users in service console. Also i see that when we point the mouse over + sign for tabs it displays the text "Add new tab", I want something like this only but for Custom console component.

Comment: This seems very similar to your previous question from 3 hours earlier - [Add text when user hovers over Custom console components which is displayed as a button in console](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/add-text-when-user-hovers-over-custom-console-components-which-is-displayed-as-a).